# Unable to expose IIS7 website to external machines

Tags: iis-7

I’m having difficulties setting up IIS7 to allow the default website to be accessible from machines other then mine. (This is for an .NET application that I’m developing).

IIS7 is installed and running on Windows 7 32bit, most of the configuration is default. I can access the default website (from my machine, where IIS is running) by pointing to localhost, my IP address, or my machine name. (I correctly get the default II7 welcome screen).

I am however unable to access the default welcome screen from other machines on the network. (I get connection timeout error messages).

Note that from these other machines, I can still:

Properly ping my IP Address.

I can also access the default (80) port, if I use something else for hosting (other then IIS).
(**Which would indicate that this is not a firewall issue**).

Suggestions ? Seems like I have to change some other II7 settings to do this, I’m just not sure what they are.

I’ve also tried editing permissions to give full access to the IIS_IUSRS and IUSR users, but that didn’t fix anything.

I am using Anonymous Authentication.

My Windows 7 firewall is turned off.

This IIS7 log files don't show anything about a remote machine hitting the server.

Comment: Worth mentioning is the fact that Ping uses ICMP and is not a layer 4 activity, meaning it has no port, like HTTP traffic. While it is common practice for network admins to disable ICMP traffic at the gateway, its possible for ping to function correctly, but web traffic to still not pass through correctly. Windows firewall, and then your router NAT or Gateway are the most likely culprits. Sticking your box in the DMZ is pretty common for development if you want to keep the firwall switched on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I figure it out ... Turns out that even though the Windows 7 Action Center explicitly said that the Windows 7 firewall was turned off, it wasn't completly. Turning it off completly fixed the problem.